# Асинхронные HTTP-вызовы grequests

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность

Всегда использовал библиотеку requests. Но как мне не изменяет память там можно посылать запрос всего на 1 `http url` и только потом на другой, по очереди. **Grequests** же как написано можно послать одновременно хоть на 10 URL тоесть асинхронность. Но как это сделать я не знаю, я уже пробовал . В файле примерно 150 url. Код:

```
import grequests
simplesite = 'http://shost-craft.su'
with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as werewolves:
        array = [row.strip()+simplesite for row in werewolves]

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = (grequests.post(u, data=params) for u in array)
grequests.map(rs)
print(rs)
```

Ждал где-то минуту 
Я так понял, это очень долго. И вот не знаю как решить данную проблему. Или все же это как раз таки быстро? 
В конце было выведено на экран: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000029AD8D29A98>`
Я хочу чтобы сразу же отослался запрос на 10 URL-адресов, не по очереди, а сразу же на 10 адресов. Или же нельзя реализовать с помощью данной библиотеки?

Comment: [примеры кода обращения к `1000_000` cайтов на gevent, twisted, asyncio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Библиотека grequests является асинхронной обёрткой над обычной requests. Соответственно когда вы отдали пачку request объектов в grequests.map(), вы получите list объектов response, примерно такого вида

```
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, None, <Response [200]>]
```

И вы уже работаете с ними как с обычными requests.Response.

Например, чтобы увидеть результат работы **первого** request`a в вашем коде, попробуйте сделать так, например:

```
import grequests
simplesite = 'http://shost-craft.su'
with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as werewolves:
    array = [row.strip()+simplesite for row in werewolves]

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = (grequests.post(u, data=params) for u in array)
responses_list = grequests.map(rs)
print(responses_list[0].text)
print(rs)
```

Если вы уточните, что конкретно вы хотите получить, возможно удастся дать более точные рекомендации

**EDIT**: под капотом эта библиотека использует gevent с пулом задач (подробнее про неё и асинхронность, например [тут](https://vovkd.github.io/gevent-tutorial/)), он блокирует вызов до конца выполнения всей пачки, но не блокирует выполнение каждой задачи в пачке. Вы можете управлять размером пула. Я написал "**первого** request`a" выше потому, что не стал заморачиваться с циклом. Могу предложить такое решение:

```
import grequests
simplesite = 'http://shost-craft.su'
with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as werewolves:
    array = [row.strip()+simplesite for row in werewolves]

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = [grequests.post(u, data=params) for u in array]
for r in grequests.imap(rs, size=10) 
    print(r.status_code, r.url)
print(rs)
```

size=10 - означает закидывать, например, по десять задач в пачке, как только выполниться одна из них докинуть ещё одну (на случай проблем с производительностью)

imap в цикле позволит вам увидеть результаты, сразу после выполнения каждой из задач

Если же вам нужны прям чистые параллельные потоки то да, только множить треды или форкать или ещё что-то, вариантов масса.

**EDIT2**: приношу извинения за свою некомпетентность по вопросу respons-статусов. Значит ситуация следующая. Учитывая, что автор grequests не использует Error-классы из requests, а делает [так](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py):

````
....
def send(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Prepares request based on parameter passed to constructor and optional      ``kwargs```.
    Then sends request and saves response to :attr:`response`

    :returns: ``Response``
    """
    merged_kwargs = {}
    merged_kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
    merged_kwargs.update(kwargs)
    try:
        self.response = self.session.request(self.method,
                                            self.url, **merged_kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        self.exception = e
        self.traceback = traceback.format_exc()
    return self
````

т.е. ловит Exception и закидывает его в ответ. Мы можем поймать его вот таким способом:

```
import grequests

def exception_handler(request, exception):
    print("Request failed", request.url) # Сообщить о невалиднсоти и выести url
    # print(str(exception)) # если хочется подробностей

simplesite = 'http://shost-craft.su'
with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as werewolves:
    array = [row.strip()+simplesite for row in werewolves]

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = [grequests.post(u, data=params) for u in array]
for r in grequests.imap(rs, size=10, exception_handler=exception_handler) 
    print(r.status_code, r.url)
```

Теперь если запрос по какой-то причине не выполнился мы, об этом узнаем. Можно получить только статуc_коды запросов которые завершились без Exception`а. Т.е. 404 и другие ошибки клиента или сети не вернуться в итоговый list. Правда остаётся вопрос как же разобрать статус. *Могу сделать предположение*, что можно попытаться вытащить из exception информацию, которую можно использовать для сравнения с одним из [этих](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py) типов ошибок, и далее раскрутить до статусов. Но учитывая, что все найденные исходники просто игнорируют этот вопрос, то тут только на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: тоесть я так понял, все же запросы отсылаются по очереди?

Comment: добавил в основной вопрос.

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Теперь валидация занимает 2 минуты, ежели раньше с обычным request методом занимала минут 15-20! От себя добавлю, что данный способ очень эффективен, особенно когда работаете с большими списками url адресов, и надо очень много отвалидировать. Меньше чем за 2 минуты у меня отвалидировалось 1050 url адресов)

Comment: Я так понял, у grequests нету правила 404 или 301?

Comment: Что за правила? С результатами grequests.imap работайте так же как и с обычным requests. Можно посмотреть заголовк http-respons и принять какое то решение на основе статус кода. Если сервер ответит 302 то requests перейдёт куда следует сам. Остальное не заню)

Comment: Под правилом я подразумеваю r.status_code == 404: Выдает ошибку, только с 200 работает

Comment: Да вы правы, я прошу прощения за дезинформацию. Полазил по исходникам. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @ ivan_susanin спасибо!

Comment: а ещё один вопрос. Я заметил что всегда выполняется по 2 запроса. То-есть 2 раза посылает запрос на один и тот-же сайт, почему так? И можно ли это как-то увеличить?

Comment: все адреса попавшие в rs, вызываются один раз. Покажите код который показывает вам, что вызов идёт дважды.

Comment: боже, я ошибся у меня было просто 2 вывода тоесть я делал print() ; print() . Я понял ошибку, убрал уже 2 раза вывод.

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку. Но можно ли реально асинхронно послать сразу же параллельно несколько запросов на сайт, то есть чтоб работало так же, только посылался не 1 запрос, а допустим 5?

Comment: самое быстрое, добавить в array дубли адресов, которые нужно вызвать несколько раз. Но пожалейте хостинги. Возможно вашу проблему можно решить другим способом. Слать множественные параллельные запросы - это плохой тон.

Comment: та нормально)) просто я не вижу другого выхода из положения, я уже 2 день ищу как решить данную проблему, и сегодня только додумался написать вам. И вот если честно, я даже не знаю как это сделать или решить. Уже и aiohttp перепробовал и gevent, всё, но не один способ не был эффективен.

Comment: Так а вы создайте вопрос об эффективности того или иного подхода, вам быстро укажут направление) Главное покажите чего добились и на чем застряли, лучше на синтетическом примере, чтобы можно было запустить и проверить. Дело и двинется... возможно)

Comment: Можете помочь в вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663170/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-pytnon3?noredirect=1#comment957757_663170 . И вы написали добавить в array дубли адресов, которые нужно вызвать несколько раз . Именно добавить тот или иной сайт в simplesite  и дублировать?

Comment: Если вы хотите один адрес, но с разными параметрами, тогда не array, а rs меняйте согласно вашим нуждам. Он же посути список. Ну 5 запросов в параллель это не "дудос" конечно, но всё же есть правила хорошего тона. Если хотите потестить, то есть например http://httpbin.org

Answer (score 2):

Попробуте такой код выкачки(Я сам его когда-то юзал):

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
pool = Pool(X)
#X это количество потоков одновременно
#можно поставить много(64 например), но учтите что сеть может не выдержать столько)
#поставьте сначала 1 и увеличивайте потихоньку

site = 'http://shost-craft.su'
params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
urls = []

with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        urls.append(row.strip() + site)

results = pool.map(lambda url: requests.post(url, data=params), urls)
print(results)
```

Comment: можете пожалуйста для удобства править спроектировавшись под мой код. И зачем URLS я тоже не могу понять.

Comment: извините, но данный код не эффективен.

Comment: @youhavenopass *"данный код не эффективен."* -- не информативно. Лучше сказать так: "подставил `X=40`, скормил 1000 ссылочек из wolfs.txt. Это заняло 10 минут, а grequest отнимает 2 минуты для тех же ссылок -- пробовал несколько раз" (в  сторону: я не понимаю почему у вас site *в конце* ссылки). Если ссылки на один и тот же сайт, то полезно session завести в каждом потоке (initializer передайте в Pool). grequests это и делает с той разницей, что Pool из gevent используется, а не ThreadPool из `multiprocessing`. Достоинство gevent, что 1000 сразу можно соединений сделать, но не нужно обычно