# Асинхронная валидация с помощью pytnon3

Tags: python, python-3.x, валидация, requests

Как отвалидировать несколько сайтов одновременно. Сразу на нескольких сервисах?
Произойдет валидация сайта, если я отправлю самый обыкновенный get-запрос на 
**[https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=[ссылка]](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=[%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0])**

```
r = requests.get('https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://shost-craft.su')
```

Или же надо посылать специальные `headers` или специальный запрос, который даст сайту знать что надо именно отвалидировать сайт. **По типу:**

```
`r = requests.get('https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://shost-craft.su', headers={'Тут что-то для валидации'}`
 print(r.headers)
```

Пришли `headers`:

```
{'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
 'Date': 'Sun, 07 May 2017 20:17:42 GMT',
 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT',
 'Public-Key-Pins': 'pin-sha256="cN0QSpPIkuwpT6iP2YjEo1bEwGpH/yiUn6yhdy+HNto="; '
                    'pin-sha256="WGJkyYjx1QMdMe0UqlyOKXtydPDVrk7sl2fV+nNm1r4="; '
                    'pin-sha256="LrKdTxZLRTvyHM4/atX2nquX9BeHRZMCxg3cf4rhc2I="; '
                    'max-age=864000',
 'Server': 'Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)',
 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15552015; preload',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, User-Agent',
 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny',
 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block'}
```

Но я не вижу никакого смысла в данных headers. Или тут все таки есть что-то что обозначает прошло валидацию или нет?

Так же есть сам `r.text`:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><link href="icon.png" rel="icon"><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"><title>Showing results for http://shost-craft.su/ - Nu Html Checker</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head><body><div id="banner"><h1 id="title"><a href="."><span>Nu Html Checker</span></a></h1></div><p class="disclaimer">This tool is an ongoing experiment in better HTML checking, and its behavior remains subject to change</p><h2 id="top">Showing results for http://shost-craft.su/</h2><form method="get"><fieldset><legend>Checker Input</legend><p class="checkboxes">Show <span class="checkboxgroup"><label title="Display the markup source of the input document." for="showsource"><input type="checkbox" name="showsource" id="showsource" value="yes">source</label><label title="Display an outline of the input document." for="showoutline"><input type="checkbox" name="showoutline" id="showoutline" value="yes">outline</label><label title="Display a report about the textual alternatives for images." for="showimagereport"><input type="checkbox" name="showimagereport" id="showimagereport" value="yes">image report</label></span><input id="show_options" type="button" value="Options…"><span class="extraoptions hidden"><span class="checkboxgroup"><label title="Check the content of all responses, including (non-200) error responses"><input type="checkbox" name="checkerrorpages" id="checkerrorpages" value="yes">check error pages</label></span><label id="user-agent-label" title="Specify the user-agent string to send in the document request">User-Agent <input name="useragent" list="useragents" value="Validator.nu/LV http://validator.w3.org/services"></label><datalist id="useragents"></datalist></span></p><div id="inputregion"><label id="inputlabel" for="doc">Document URL:</label><input type="url" name="doc" id="doc" pattern="(?:(?:https?://.+)|(?:data:.+))?" title="Absolute IRI (http, https or data only) of the document to be checked." tabindex="0" autofocus="autofocus" value="http://shost-craft.su/"></div><p><input value="Check" type="submit" id="submit"></p></fieldset></form><script src="script.js"></script><div id="results"><ol><li class="error"><p><strong>Error</strong>: <span><code>style</code> element between <code>head</code> and <code>body</code>.</span></p><p class="location">From line <span class="first-line">14</span>, column <span class="first-col">5</span>; to line <span class="last-line">14</span>, column <span class="last-col">11</span></p><p class="extract"><code>head&gt;<span class="lf" title="Line break">↩</span>    <b>&lt;style&gt;</b><span class="lf" title="Line break">↩</span>    b</code></p></li><li class="error fatal"><p><strong>Fatal Error</strong>: <span>Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.</span></p><p class="location">From line <span class="first-line">14</span>, column <span class="first-col">5</span>; to line <span class="last-line">14</span>, column <span class="last-col">11</span></p><p class="extract"><code>head&gt;<span class="lf" title="Line break">↩</span>    <b>&lt;style&gt;</b><span class="lf" title="Line break">↩</span>    b</code></p></li></ol><p class="failure">There were errors.</p><div class="details"><p class="msgschema">Used the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.</p><p class="msgmediatype">Used the HTML parser. Externally specified character encoding was UTF-8.</div><p class="stats">Total execution time 340 milliseconds.</p></div><hr><div id="about"><p><a href="about.html">About this checker</a> • <a href="about.html#issues">Report an issue</a> • <span class="version">Version: 17.5.7</span></p></div></body></html>`

Comment: В ответе, который валидатор вам присылает после вашего запроса, вы по каким-то причинам не нашли ответов на свои вопросы?

Comment: @andreymal я изменил вопрос, если честно я не нашел никаких факторов что прошло валидацию

Comment: headers отпечатали, теперь собственно сам ответ отпечатайте-то :)

Comment: @andreymal <Response [200]> это то или нет?

Comment: Если вы не понимаете как *один* сайт "отвалидировать", то сперва это узнайте. И только, зная как один сайт обработать, уже затем несколько сайтов пробуйте (начните с простого цикла и если это не достаточно в вашем случае, то явно упомяните это в вопросе).

Comment: `print(r.text)` же, чё вы как документацию по requests не читали)

Comment: @andreymal я читал, но не нашел раздела заданного под мой вопрос. Если вы кинете ссылку я обязательно прочитаю, и узнаю много чего нового)

Comment: Выполните запрос в адресной строке браузера. Вы перейдёте на сайт. Найдите там ответ на вопрос о валидации. Затем в браузере откройте исходный код. Вы увидите, что он совпадает выводом r.text в вашем коде. Теперь формулировка: найдите в r.text элементы совпадающие с таковыми в браузере. В качестве почитать я бы посоветовал Райн Митчел "Скрапинг веб-сайтов с помощью python". Там есть ответы на все ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет такой валидации c помощью aiohttp и asyncio? Код:

```
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        delay = response.headers.get("DELAY")
        date = response.headers.get("DATE")
        print("{}:{} with delay {}".format(date, response.url, delay))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
    site = "http://shost-craft.su"


    with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\cruel.need\\wolfs.txt") as werewolves:
            array = [row.strip()+site for row in werewolves]
    for url in array:
        tasks = []

        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)
        print(url)

        async with ClientSession() as session:
            for i in range(r):

                task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
                tasks.append(task)

            responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            await responses

number = 10
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Нашел https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html. Или тут лучше что-то подправить? :)